# How can I get the file name from an image picked from the gallery?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the filename from the gallery but the library I am using doesn't seem to have the method to retrieve the file name but it has the method for retrieving the file path, I am using the Xam.Plugin.Media. I need the filename to pass it as an argument in the other method  I am using. Here is my code:

```
   var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new 
   Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
            {
                PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
           
            });


            if (file == null) return;
            imgChoosed.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });

            // computerVision = new ComputerVisionViewModel();

           //I need to pass the file name as an argument here
           // var result = await computerVision.ConnectToVisualRecognition(file.Path,file.Name);
```

Comment: You can get it from filePath

Comment: How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this.

```
var fileNameWithExtenstion = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
var fileNameWithoutExtenstion = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
```